# Can't install "react native cli" globally by using git bash

Tags: react-native, npm, installation, failed-installation

When I type in "npm install -g react-native-cli" at git bash I get following errors:

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at: npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     C:\Users\TOSHIBA İ5\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-10-19T04_04_05_774Z-debug.log

I have already installed npm and added it's directory to PATH variable and when i type "which npm" at git bash it shows the directory so there is no problem about the installation of npm. But it still gives these errors and I am stuck.

Note: I am following the instructions on https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-on-windows-90d85a72ae65

Answer (score 2):

This could happen in some npm old versions. Make sure you are using an updated one.

```
npm install -g npm
```

Some linux distros have old versions of npm and node on their packages and you need to install it manually.

Edit: I just saw you have windows. Nevermind, still the old version could be a problem.

Comment: it gives the exact same errors when I type it in both at windows cmd and git bash

Comment: What version of node and npm do you have?